# In SQL, Main table should match with lookup table for the multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Main Table should match with lookup table for the given columns and if its not match and the look up table has any null values then it should match with Null values (here null = any value)

**Scenario**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MAIN_TABLE (
NAMEID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
COL1 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
COL2 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
COL3 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
COL4 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_MAIN_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (NAMEID)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.LOOKUP_TABLE (
COL1 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
COL2 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
COL3 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
COL4 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
RES_COL VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.LOOKUP_TABLE
INSERT INTO dbo.LOOKUP_TABLE VALUES('AA','BB', 'CC', NULL, 'Rule1')
INSERT INTO dbo.LOOKUP_TABLE VALUES('AA','BB', NULL, NULL, 'Rule2')
INSERT INTO dbo.LOOKUP_TABLE VALUES('AA',NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Rule3')
INSERT INTO dbo.LOOKUP_TABLE VALUES(NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Rule4')

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MAIN_TABLE
INSERT INTO dbo.MAIN_TABLE VALUES('NameId1','AA','BB', 'CC', 'DD' )
INSERT INTO dbo.MAIN_TABLE VALUES('NameId2','AA','BB', 'CC', NULL )
INSERT INTO dbo.MAIN_TABLE VALUES('NameId3','AA','BB', NULL, NULL )
INSERT INTO dbo.MAIN_TABLE VALUES('NameId4','AA', NULL, NULL, NULL )

INSERT INTO dbo.MAIN_TABLE VALUES('NameId5',NULL,'BB', 'CC', 'DD' )
INSERT INTO dbo.MAIN_TABLE VALUES('NameId6',NULL,NULL, 'CC', 'DD' )
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
NAMEID  |  RES_COL
-----------------
NameId1 | Rule1
NameId2 | Rule1
NameId3 | Rule2
NameId4 | Rule3
NameId5 | Rule4
NameId6 | Rule4
```

**I tried something like the below query but its returning duplicate rows with all the other values**

```
SELECT MN.NAMEID, MAP.RES_COL  FROM MAIN_TABLE MN
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT * FROM LOOKUP_TABLE LKP
  WHERE  
   ( CHECKSUM(MN.COL1) = CHECKSUM(LKP.COL1) OR LKP.COL1 IS NULL )
  AND
   ( CHECKSUM(MN.COL2) = CHECKSUM(LKP.COL2) OR LKP.COL2 IS NULL)
  AND
   ( CHECKSUM(MN.COL3) = CHECKSUM(LKP.COL3) OR LKP.COL3 IS NULL)
  AND
   ( CHECKSUM(MN.COL4) = CHECKSUM(LKP.COL4) OR LKP.COL4 IS NULL )
) MAP

ORDER BY MN.NAMEID ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get multiple matches because of the `NULL` = matches anything rule. So for any Name, `Rule4` will definitely matches as it is NULL for all columns

If you only wanted the best matches, use a `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.MAIN_TABLE m
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT  TOP 1 *
            FROM    dbo.LOOKUP_TABLE l
            WHERE   (l.COL1 = m.COL1 OR l.COL1 IS NULL)
            AND     (l.COL2 = m.COL2 OR l.COL2 IS NULL)
            AND     (l.COL3 = m.COL3 OR l.COL3 IS NULL)
            AND     (l.COL4 = m.COL4 OR l.COL4 IS NULL)
            ORDER BY 
                CASE WHEN l.COL1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
            +   CASE WHEN l.COL2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
            +   CASE WHEN l.COL3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
            +   CASE WHEN l.COL4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
        ) l
```

any particular reason you uses `CHECKSUM()` instead of a simple equal `=` ?

Comment: I used checksum to match with NULL = NULL, also its very clear to compare the values.

Comment: I don't think `checksum()` guarantees to gives you a unique value. I would do a `=` comparison to be save

Comment: take a look at this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/12/09/checksum-and-binary_checksum-might-not-return-unique-values-for-different-inputs/

Comment: Sure , will check that. And, thank you for the perfect answer, you saved my day :)